# Unable to delete from a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is a piece of mysql code

```
DELETE FROM tbl_node_details WHERE ParentId IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

This works fine and all rows are deleted with the respective ids.
But when is do  like this

```
SET @a='1,2,3,4,5'
DELETE FROM tbl_node_details WHERE ParentId IN (@a);
```

it doesn't work...y is it so??

Comment: You are passing as integer in first case for ParentId and string in the second case. Moreover you cannot pass parameters in query statements ... use a function instead and pass them as parameters

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameters with in statement. Try to loop or build string wo parameters

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use parameters within query statements. Try using loops.

Answer (score 0):

As @hkutluay stated this won't work.
Assuming you get your parameters from another table you can do :

```
DELETE FROM tbl_node_details WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT <id_col_name> FROM <other_table> WHERE <condition>);
```